# Octave: Problems with plotting discrete signals, Nyquist sampling

Tags: matlab, octave, sampling, discrete-mathematics

I created a program on Octave with the purpose of creating a continuous-time signal with noise in it, this noise was then supposed to be discretely sampled(shown as the orange lines fitting inside the sine wave below). This was supposed to be the expected output after completing the code.

[image]

However, while I did manage to get the same exact wave, what I did not get was the discrete sampling of the continuous-time signal, getting this as a result.

[image]

I'm not sure as to why the lines did not fit in between the graph since I had applied the same Nyquist Theorem to them, the code below will better explain what I mean.

```
%Time Base
t = 0:0.001:1.8;

%Nyquist Frequencies
Fn1 = 1;
Fn2 = 6;

%Nyquist Rates 
Fnr1 = 2*(Fn1);
Fnr2 = 2*(Fn2);

%Sampling Period
Sp1 = 5*(Fnr1);
Sp2 = 5*(Fnr2);

Ts1 = 1/(Sp1);
Ts2 = 1/(Sp2);
T1 = 1/(Fn1);
T2 = 1/(Fn2);

%Number of Samples
N1 = (T1/Ts1); 
n1 = 0:1:N1-1; 
N2 = (T2/Ts2); 
n2 = 0:1:N2-1; 

nTs1 = n1 * Ts1; 
nTs2 = n2 * Ts2; 

x_c = sin(2*pi*Fn1*nTs1);
x_c2 = sin(2*pi*Fn2*nTs2);

x_c1 = sin(2*pi*Fn1*t);
x_2 = sin(2*pi*Fn2*t);

signal = x_c1 + x_2;
ct = nTs1 + nTs2;
nqsignal = x_c + x_c2;

%Second Part
h = stem(ct, nqsignal, 'linewidth', 2);
hold
plot(t, signal, 'linewidth', 2)
lgd = legend('Discrete Data', 'Continuous Data');
set (lgd, "fontsize", 12)
set(gca,'XTick',[0:0.2:1.8]);
set(gca,'YTick',[-2:0.5:2]);
title('Time vs Magnitude','fontweight','bold','fontsize',16);
xlabel('Time(s)','fontweight','bold','fontsize',14)
ylabel('Magnitude','fontweight','bold','fontsize',14)
grid
```

I just want to know where I went wrong and how I could fix such a mistake.